# PrimeFaces Wizard not working embedded in page

Tags: java, netbeans, primefaces

I created a PrimeFaces Wizard from scratch in NetBeans and it was mostly working (still couldn't get the confirmation.xhtml page to render after submission...).  I then moved the code for the form into a prebuilt html page, and now the Wizard is not working.  It displays the first tab, but then "next" button has no effect.

Can anyone see a reason the form would (mostly) work in segregation, but not when put into another html page (.xhtml).

Original wizard: (Please let me know if you can figure out what the issue is where it won't submit)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Input page</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>   
            <p:wizard id="wizard">
                <p:tab title="Booking" id="booking">
                    <p:panel header="Booking">
                        <p:messages/>
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2">

                            <h:outputLabel for="firstName" 
                                           value="First Name" 
                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
                            <h:inputText id="firstName" 
                                         label="First Name" 
                                         value="#{userBean.firstName}" 
                                         required="true"/>
                            <h:outputLabel for="lastName" 
                                           value="Last Name" 
                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
                            <h:inputText id="lastName" label="Last Name" 
                                         value="#{userBean.lastName}" 
                                         required="true"/>
                            <h:outputLabel for="email" 
                                           value="Email" 
                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
                            <h:inputText id="email" label="Email" 
                                         value="#{userBean.email}" 
                                         required="true"/>


                            <p:outputLabel for="console" value="Time of Day:" />
                            <p:selectOneRadio id="console" value="#{userBean.timeOfDay}">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Morning" itemValue="Morning" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Afternoon" itemValue="Afternoon" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Evening" itemValue="Evening" />
                            </p:selectOneRadio>


                            <h:outputLabel for="checkout_date"
                                           value="Checkout Date"
                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>

                            <p:calendar id="checkout_date"
                                        label="Checkout Date"
                                        value="#{userBean.checkout_date}"/>

                            <h:outputLabel for="checkin_date"
                                           value="Checkin Date"
                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>

                            <p:calendar id="checkin_date"
                                        label="Checkin Date"
                                        value="#{userBean.checkin_date}"/>
                            <p:outputLabel for="type" value="Type:" />
                            <p:selectOneRadio id="type" value="#{userBean.type}">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Cheap" itemValue="Cheap" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Standard" itemValue="Standard" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Lux" itemValue="Lux" />
                            </p:selectOneRadio>
                            <h:outputLabel for="adults" value="Adults:" />
                            <p:spinner id="adults" value="#{userBean.numAdults}" />
                            <h:outputLabel for="children" value="Children:" />
                            <p:spinner id="children" value="#{userBean.numChildren}" />

                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>
                </p:tab>

                <p:tab title="Payment" id="payment">
                    <p:panel header="Booking">
                        <p:messages/>
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                            <h:outputLabel for="creditCard" 
                                           value="Credit Card Number:" 
                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
                            <h:inputText id="creditCard" 
                                         label="Credit Card" 
                                         value="#{userBean.creditCard}" 
                                         required="true"/>
                            <h:outputLabel for="address1" 
                                           value="Address:" 
                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
                            <h:inputText id="address1" 
                                         label="address" 
                                         value="#{userBean.address1}" 
                                         required="true"/>
                            <h:outputLabel for="address2" 
                                           value="Address 2:" 
                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
                            <h:inputText id="address2" 
                                         label="address 2" 
                                         value="#{userBean.address2}" 
                                         required="true"/>
                            <h:outputLabel for="city" 
                                           value="City:" 
                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
                            <h:inputText id="city" 
                                         label="city" 
                                         value="#{userBean.city}" 
                                         required="true"/>
                            <h:outputLabel for="state" 
                                           value="State:" 
                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
                            <h:inputText id="state" 
                                         label="state" 
                                         value="#{userBean.state}" 
                                         required="true"/>
                            <h:outputLabel for="zip" 
                                           value="Zip:" 
                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
                            <h:inputText id="zip" 
                                         label="zip" 
                                         value="#{userBean.zip}" 
                                         required="true"/>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab title="Submit" id="submit">
                    <p:panel header="Booking">
                        <p:messages/>
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                            <h:outputLabel for="message" 
                                           value="Message:" 
                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
                            <p:inputTextarea rows="10" cols="30" completeMethod="#{userBean.message}" />

                            <h:outputLabel for="agree_terms" 
                                           value="I have read and agree to terms: " 
                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{userBean.agree_terms}" />

                             <h:outputLabel for="total" 
                                           value="Total:" 
                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
                            <h:inputText id="total" 
                                         label="total" 
                                         value="#{userBean.total}"
                                         disabled="true"
                                         required="true"/>

                            <p:commandButton id="submitButton"
                                                 value="Submit" 
                                                 action="#{userBean.saveUser()}"
                                                 process="@this"                                                 
                                                  />




                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>

                </p:tab>


            </p:wizard>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

New index.xhtml file (the pasted form is below the content marker):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Input page</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no" />
        <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="booking/css/booking.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/camera.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
        <script src="js/superfish.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.ui.totop.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.equalheights.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobilemenu.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
        <script src="js/camera.js"></script>

        <script src="js/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js"></script>

        <script src="booking/js/booking.js"></script>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <header>
            <div class="menu_block ">
                <div class="container_12">
                    <div class="grid_12">
                        <nav class="horizontal-nav full-width horizontalNav-notprocessed">
                            <ul class="sf-menu">
                                <li class="current"><a href="index.xhtml">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="index-1.html">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="index-2.html">Cars</a></li>
                                <li><a href="index-3.html">Services</a></li>
                                <li><a href="index-4.html">Contacts</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container_12">
                <div class="grid_12">
                    <h1>
                        <a href="index.xhtml">
                            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Your Happy Family" />
                        </a>
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </header>
        <div class="slider_wrapper ">
            <div id="camera_wrap" class="">
                <div data-src="images/slide.jpg" ></div>
                <div data-src="images/slide1.jpg" ></div>
                <div data-src="images/slide2.jpg"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container_12">
            <div class="grid_4">
                <div class="banner">
                    <div class="maxheight">
                        <div class="banner_title">
                            <img src="images/icon1.png" alt="" />
                            <div class="extra_wrapper">Fast&amp;
                                <div class="color1">Safe</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        Dorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscinger elit. In mollis erat mattis neque facilisis, sit ameter ultricies erat rutrum. Cras facilisis, nulla vel viver auctor, leo magna sodales felis, quis malesuad
                        <a href="#" class="fa fa-share-square"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid_4">
                <div class="banner">
                    <div class="maxheight">
                        <div class="banner_title">
                            <img src="images/icon2.png" alt="" />
                            <div class="extra_wrapper">Best
                                <div class="color1">Prices</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        Hem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscinger elit. In mollis erat mattis neque facilisis, sit ameter ultricies erat rutrum. Cras facilisis, nulla vel viver auctor, leo magna sodales felis, quis malesuader
                        <a href="#" class="fa fa-share-square"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid_4">
                <div class="banner">
                    <div class="maxheight">
                        <div class="banner_title">
                            <img src="images/icon3.png" alt="" />
                            <div class="extra_wrapper">Package
                                <div class="color1">Delivery</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        Kurem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscinger elit. In mollis erat mattis neque facilisis, sit ameter ultricies erat rutrum. Cras facilisis, nulla vel viver auctor, leo magna sodales felis, quis malesuki
                        <a href="#" class="fa fa-share-square"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="c_phone">
            <div class="container_12">
                <div class="grid_12">
                    <div class="fa fa-phone"></div>+ 1800 559 6580
                    <span>ORDER NOW!</span>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--==============================Content=================================-->
        <div class="content"><div class="ic">More Website Templates @ TemplateMonster.com - April 07, 2014!</div>
            <div class="container_12">
                <div class="grid_5">
                    <h3>Booking Form</h3>
                    <div id="jeffsform">
                        <h:form>   
                            <p:wizard id="wizard">
                                <p:tab title="Booking" id="booking">
                                    <p:panel header="Booking">
                                        <p:messages/>
                                        <h:panelGrid columns="2">

                                            <h:outputLabel for="firstName" 
                                                           value="First Name" 
                                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
                                            <h:inputText id="firstName" 
                                                         label="First Name" 
                                                         value="#{userBean.firstName}" 
                                                         required="true"/>
                                            <h:outputLabel for="lastName" 
                                                           value="Last Name" 
                                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
                                            <h:inputText id="lastName" label="Last Name" 
                                                         value="#{userBean.lastName}" 
                                                         required="true"/>
                                            <h:outputLabel for="email" 
                                                           value="Email" 
                                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
                                            <h:inputText id="email" label="Email" 
                                                         value="#{userBean.email}" 
                                                         required="true"/>


                                            <p:outputLabel for="timeOfDay" value="Time of Day:" />
                                            <p:selectOneRadio id="timeOfDay" value="#{userBean.timeOfDay}">
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Morning" itemValue="Morning" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Afternoon" itemValue="Afternoon" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Evening" itemValue="Evening" />
                                            </p:selectOneRadio>


                                            <h:outputLabel for="checkout_date"
                                                           value="Checkout Date"
                                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>

                                            <p:calendar id="checkout_date"
                                                        label="Checkout Date"
                                                        value="#{userBean.checkout_date}"/>

                                            <h:outputLabel for="checkin_date"
                                                           value="Checkin Date"
                                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>

                                            <p:calendar id="checkin_date"
                                                        label="Checkin Date"
                                                        value="#{userBean.checkin_date}"/>
                                            <p:outputLabel for="type" value="Type:" />
                                            <p:selectOneRadio id="type" value="#{userBean.type}">
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Cheap" itemValue="Cheap" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Standard" itemValue="Standard" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Lux" itemValue="Lux" />
                                            </p:selectOneRadio>
                                            <h:outputLabel for="adults" value="Adults:" />
                                            <p:spinner id="adults" value="#{userBean.numAdults}" />
                                            <h:outputLabel for="children" value="Children:" />
                                            <p:spinner id="children" value="#{userBean.numChildren}" />

                                        </h:panelGrid>
                                    </p:panel>
                                </p:tab>

                                <p:tab title="Payment" id="payment">
                                    <p:panel header="Booking">
                                        <p:messages/>
                                        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                                            <h:outputLabel for="creditCard" 
                                                           value="Credit Card Number:" 
                                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
                                            <h:inputText id="creditCard" 
                                                         label="Credit Card" 
                                                         value="#{userBean.creditCard}" 
                                                         required="true"/>
                                            <h:outputLabel for="address1" 
                                                           value="Address:" 
                                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
                                            <h:inputText id="address1" 
                                                         label="address" 
                                                         value="#{userBean.address1}" 
                                                         required="true"/>
                                            <h:outputLabel for="address2" 
                                                           value="Address 2:" 
                                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
                                            <h:inputText id="address2" 
                                                         label="address 2" 
                                                         value="#{userBean.address2}" 
                                                         required="true"/>
                                            <h:outputLabel for="city" 
                                                           value="City:" 
                                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
                                            <h:inputText id="city" 
                                                         label="city" 
                                                         value="#{userBean.city}" 
                                                         required="true"/>
                                            <h:outputLabel for="state" 
                                                           value="State:" 
                                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
                                            <h:inputText id="state" 
                                                         label="state" 
                                                         value="#{userBean.state}" 
                                                         required="true"/>
                                            <h:outputLabel for="zip" 
                                                           value="Zip:" 
                                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
                                            <h:inputText id="zip" 
                                                         label="zip" 
                                                         value="#{userBean.zip}" 
                                                         required="true"/>
                                        </h:panelGrid>
                                    </p:panel>
                                </p:tab>
                                <p:tab title="Submit" id="submit">
                                    <p:panel header="Booking">
                                        <p:messages/>
                                        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                                            <h:outputLabel for="message" 
                                                           value="Message:" 
                                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
                                            <p:inputTextarea rows="10" cols="30" completeMethod="#{userBean.message}" />

                                            <h:outputLabel for="agree_terms" 
                                                           value="I have read and agree to terms: " 
                                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
                                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{userBean.agree_terms}" />

                                            <h:outputLabel for="total" 
                                                           value="Total:" 
                                                           styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
                                            <h:inputText id="total" 
                                                         label="total" 
                                                         value="#{userBean.total}" />
                                            <!--disabled="true"/>-->

                                            <p:commandButton id="submitButton" value="Submit" action="#{userBean.saveUser}"/>



                                        </h:panelGrid>
                                    </p:panel>

                                </p:tab>


                            </p:wizard>
                        </h:form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_6 prefix_1">
                    <a href="index2.html" class="type"><img src="images/page1_img1.jpg" alt=""/><span class="type_caption">Economy</span></a>
                    <a href="index2.html" class="type"><img src="images/page1_img2.jpg" alt=""/><span class="type_caption">Standard</span></a>
                    <a href="index2.html" class="type"><img src="images/page1_img3.jpg" alt=""/><span class="type_caption">Lux</span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--==============================footer=================================-->
        <footer>
            <div class="container_12">
                <div class="grid_12">
                    <div class="f_phone"><span>Call Us:</span> + 1800 559 6580</div>
                    <div class="socials">
                        <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
                        <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
                        <a href="#" class="fa fa-google-plus"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="copy">
                        <div class="st1">
                            <div class="brand">Tour<span class="color1">T</span>axi </div>
                            &copy; 2014 | <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a> </div> Website designed by <a href="http://www.templatemonster.com/" rel="nofollow">TemplateMonster.com</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </footer>














    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: In first example, it looks to me as you should have process="submit" on the button. Also by default it does'nt update anything. Should'nt it?

Answer (score 0):

In second example I see a lot of included javascript.
May be duplicate include jquery, or jquery version conflict:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Check your browser console for errors..